# Postgres Python Query import pg vs import psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm am working on editing a python script and I need to check if a table exists. The code works however since I am now trying to check if a table exists I need to first understand what is going on.

The code currently has:

```
import pg
con = pg.connect(...)
```

and a bunch of calls to:

```
con.query(...)
```

I found this  example on SO: [Checking if a postgresql table exists under python (and probably Psycopg2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874113/checking-if-a-postgresql-table-exists-under-python-and-probably-psycopg2)
 but I am unsure if `psycopg2` is the same as `pg` and I can't seem to find any documentation on `pg` so I don't know if `import pg` can do `con.exucute(...)` simular to how `psycopg2` can.

Everytime I search for `pg` I get documentation for `psycopg2`.

Anyone know the differences between the two?
Can I use `con.execute()` and `con.cursor()` for `pg`?

Comment: `pg` is most likely a reference to the PyGreSQL library, which is DB-API compliant, as is psycopg2, so they should operate the same--though ordinarily you would use the `execute` method of a cursor object rather than of the connection object.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Does a `cursor` object march with an `execute` and store the last value of the execute?

Comment: The results of `execute()` can be obtained through the cursor object with `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchall()`.  The complete DB-API specifications are here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/.  Whichever library you use may have some additional features; you should check that documentation also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg` refers to the PyGreSQL driver:

http://www.pygresql.org/

> PyGreSQL is a Python module that interfaces to a PostgreSQL database. It embeds the PostgreSQL query library to allow easy use of the powerful PostgreSQL features from a Python script or application.
>
> PyGreSQL consists of two parts: the “classic” PyGreSQL interface provided by the pg module and the newer DB-API 2.0 compliant interface provided by the pgdb module.